# How do I extract a color from part of an image and use in keying?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How do I extract a color from part of an image and use in keying?

I want to pull out a rect from the corner, like 10x10 to 100x100 and feed it into the key color of the keying node. This is so I can auto detect if its a green screen or blue screen input.

[image]

Comment: Just plug the crop output into the Key Color put of the keyer.

Comment: @3pointedit I tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps you could add a "scale to scene" dimensions node after the crop? Shouldn't require this however.

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to scale that to the image size

[image: DOG]